# User registration form with checkbox field

Tags: users, field, registration, checkboxes

Hi I have user registration form with multiple custom fields. They all work fine except for the field I have as a checkbox. It returns an error of 'my-field' is invalid. Any ideas anyone? code below (field in question is towards the bottom)...

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="login-form">
            {{ getCsrfInput() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ url('collection/') }}">

            <h3>Register</h3>


            <p>To browse our collection please register your information below.</p>

            <p>Already registered? <a href="#login-modal" class="toggle-modal-trigger">Login</a>.</p>

            {{ entry.contentBeforeForm }}

            {% macro errorList(errors) %}
                {% if errors %}
                    <ul class="errors">
                        {% for error in errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            {% endmacro %}

            {% from _self import errorList %}



            <h4><label for="firstName">First name</label></h4>
            <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.firstName }}"{% endif %} placeholder="First name">
            {{ account is defined and account ? errorList(account.getErrors('firstName')) }}

            <h4><label for="lastName">Last name</label></h4>
            <input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName" {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.lastName }}"{% endif %} placeholder="Last name"> 
            {{ account is defined and account ? errorList(account.getErrors('lastName')) }} 

            <h4><label for="company">Company</label></h4>
            <input id="company" type="text" name="fields[company]" {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.company }}"{% endif %} placeholder="Company">  
            {{ account is defined and account ? errorList(account.getErrors('company')) }} 

            <h4><label for="phone">Phone</label></h4>
            <input id="phone" type="text" name="fields[phone]" {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.phone }}"{% endif %} placeholder="Phone">
            {{ account is defined and account ? errorList(account.getErrors('phone')) }}

            <h4><label for="username">Username</label></h4>
            <input id="username" type="text" name="username" {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.username }}"{% endif -%} placeholder="Username">

            {% if account is defined %}
                {{ errorList(account.getErrors('username')) }}
            {% endif %}

            <h4><label for="email">Email</label></h4>
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email" {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.email }}"{% endif %} placeholder="Email">

            {% if account is defined %}
                {{ errorList(account.getErrors('email')) }}
            {% endif %}


            <h4><label for="password">Password</label></h4>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password">

            {% if account is defined %}
                {{ errorList(account.getErrors('password')) }}
            {% endif %}

            {# HERE IS THE FIELD CAUSING THE ERROR #}
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="termsAgreement" name="fields[termsAgreement]" {%- if account is defined %}value="1" checked{% endif %}>
             I agree to terms and conditions above
            </label>
            {{ account is defined and account ? errorList(account.getErrors('termsAgreement')) }}

            <input type="submit" value="Register">

        </form>
```

Comment: Is it really a checkbox field or a lightswitch field? Because checkboxes must be defined as an array. If you are doing it for a lightswitch field you have to pass either `1/true` or `0/false`. Currently you are sending a `null` value if the field is not checked as well

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone else has this issue i got it working with these modifications.

I think the hidden field was required for the possibility of null values.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[myCustomField]" value="no">
```

It also required the extra [] brackets after the field name in the checkbox option (as checkbox fields are an array).

```
name="fields[myCustomField][]"
```

Here's my code thats working:

```
            <input type="hidden" name="fields[termsAgreement]" value="no">
            <input type="checkbox" id="termsAgreement" name="fields[termsAgreement][]" value="yes">

             I agree to terms and conditions above
            </label>
            {{ account is defined and account ? errorList(account.getErrors('termsAgreement')) }}
```

Comment: This helps, thanks. First had an empty value like <input type="hidden" name="fields[termsAgreement]" value="">, but that didn't force the error. It needs to be a value that is not listed in the field settings.